# There is a Login Bug

Tags: bug

I normally login to Stackoverflow using Wordpress. There apparently is a cookie with this information because when I login, Wordpress is selected and it asks for my Wordpress user id.

When I give my id (as instructed) and try to login, I get the error "No OpenID identifier was provided." If I click the Wordpress icon first, this does not happen.

Comment: Yeah, there's a problem with how we're trying to "remember" what you selected. Thanks for the report.